# Spark csv write to S3 from dataset failed with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, aws-java-sdk

I am using `spark 3.2.2` and need to write a dataset to s3 in csv format.

I have both `aws-java-sdk-bundle` and `hadoop-aws` as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.901</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have my spark s3 write code  within my class from driver as:

```
 public void saveRejectsS3(Dataset<Row> rejects,String date)
    {
        String path =  "s3a://test-bucket/"+ date;
        logger.info("s3  path:= " +path );
        try {
            rejects.show(1);
            rejects.repartition(1).write().format("csv").option("header", "true").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                    .save(path);
            logger.info("saveS3 successful");
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("error:"+e);
        }
}
```

when I call this function I get error as

> java.io.IOException: regular upload failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V

**STACKTRACE**:

```
    2022-11-29 03:24:22,182+0000 [main] WARN  AbstractS3ACommitterFactory:90  - Using standard FileOutputCommitter to commit work. This is slow and potentially unsafe.
2022-11-29 03:24:24,233+0000 [task-result-getter-2] WARN  TaskSetManager:69  - Lost task 0.0 in stage 304.0 (TID 26881) (10.47.202.71 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:1000)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CsvOutputWriter.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:311)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: regular upload failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.extractException(S3AUtils.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.putObject(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.close(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:996)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3DataSource$Utils.cleanupDataSource(S3DataSource.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1862)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.putObjectDirect(S3AFileSystem.java:2432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.lambda$putObject$6(WriteOperationHelper.java:517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$4(Invoker.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.retry(WriteOperationHelper.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.putObject(WriteOperationHelper.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.lambda$putObject$0(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
    ... 3 more

2022-11-29 03:24:25,175+0000 [task-result-getter-0] ERROR TaskSetManager:73  - Task 0 in stage 304.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
2022-11-29 03:24:25,181+0000 [main] ERROR FileFormatWriter:94  - Aborting job 651308ed-f3d7-4e4b-ac87-9781282ec58a.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 304.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 304.0 (TID 26884) (10.47.202.71 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:1000)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CsvOutputWriter.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:311)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: regular upload failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.extractException(S3AUtils.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.putObject(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.close(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:996)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3DataSource$Utils.cleanupDataSource(S3DataSource.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1862)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.putObjectDirect(S3AFileSystem.java:2432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.lambda$putObject$6(WriteOperationHelper.java:517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$4(Invoker.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.retry(WriteOperationHelper.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.putObject(WriteOperationHelper.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.lambda$putObject$0(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
    ... 3 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.impression.utils.ImpressionDataWriter.saveRejectsS3(ImpressionDataWriter.java:136)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.impression.utils.ImpressionDataWriter.saveRejects(ImpressionDataWriter.java:118)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.impression.spark.AccountEventProcessor.processInserts(AccountEventProcessor.java:114)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.impression.spark.ImpressionSparkJob.processData(ImpressionSparkJob.java:221)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.impression.spark.ImpressionSparkJob.execute(ImpressionSparkJob.java:106)
    at com.capitalone.customer.relationships.batch.Impression.main(Impression.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:1000)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CsvOutputWriter.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:311)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: regular upload failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.extractException(S3AUtils.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.putObject(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.close(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:996)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.release(Ljava/io/Closeable;Lcom/amazonaws/thirdparty/apache/logging/Log;)V
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3DataSource$Utils.cleanupDataSource(S3DataSource.java:48)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1862)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.putObjectDirect(S3AFileSystem.java:2432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.lambda$putObject$6(WriteOperationHelper.java:517)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$4(Invoker.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.retry(WriteOperationHelper.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.WriteOperationHelper.putObject(WriteOperationHelper.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ABlockOutputStream.lambda$putObject$0(S3ABlockOutputStream.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor$RunnableWithPermitRelease.run(SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.java:196)
    ... 3 more
2022-11-29 03:24:25,747+0000 [main] ERROR ImpressionDataWriter:139  - error:org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted
```

I get the above error and csv file isn't created while the date folder is being created in s3.
I have tried upgrading aws bundle  to higher version and still getting the same error:

Comment: Try with `aws-java-sdk-bundle 1.11.375` , `aws-java-sdk-s3 1.11.375` and `hadoop-aws  3.2.0`

Comment: no vrikanth, that doesn't help as you add two versions of bits of the aws sdk to the cp